# Get data from between temporary table create and drop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite, temp-tables

I have optimized the peformance of one of my SQLite scripts by adding a temporary table so now it looks like this:

```sql
create temp table temp.cache as select * from (...);

--- Complex query.
select * from (...);

drop table temp.cache;
```

The issue with this solution is that I no longer can use Pandas' `pd.read_sql_query` because it doesn't return any result and throws an exception saying I'm allowed to execute only a single statement.

What would you say is the preferable solution? I can think of two:

1. Plan-A: There is some trick to extract the data anyway or
2. Plan-B: I need to call python's SQLite `execute` function before and after using Pandas to handle the temporary table.

Comment: Why not combine both select statements with something like `select * from (select * from whatever) as x;`

Comment: @AnonCoward The `complex query` contains 12 CTEs and the first one that precalculates some values and is used in multiple joins makes this query run forever. When I cache it in a temp table, the query executes in less than a second :-]